# Count grouped records by day

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having some minor trouble with creating a query in Access using SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to create a query that looks like this

[image: Query Example]

The database looks like this (I had to recreate it with generic names)
LOG

```
dispatcher  tech    zone   serviceorder  casesummary      resolution         date_
John Doe    Trump    MZ     13458215    MZ/ description   Replaced Printer   8/1/2015
John Doe    Clinton  Core   45821654    Core/ description Added Paper        8/1/2015
John Doe    Smith    WA     12458254    WA/ description   WOA                8/1/2015
John Doe    Smith    WA     15465224    WA/ description   Replaced Printer   8/2/2015
John Doe    Williams WB     15468521    WB/ description   Replaced Scangun   8/2/2015
John Doe    Jones    WFF    48593258    WFF/ description  Replaced Scangun   8/3/2015
John Doe    Jones    WFF    15487528    WFF/ description  Replaced printer   8/4/2015
Bob Dole    Jones    WA     65328451    WA/ description   WOA                8/4/2015
Bob Dole    Williams WB     48521596    WB/ description   WOA                8/5/2015
Bob Dole    Trump    WC     34852369    WC/ description   WOA                8/5/2015
Bob Dole    Trump    WC     63214789    WC/ description   Replaced Printer   8/5/2015
Bob Dole    Williams WB     52369852    WB/ description   Added Paper        8/6/2015
Bob Dole    Johnson  WE     25896325    WE/ description   WOA                8/6/2015
Jack Hill   Jones    WC     78521478    WC/ description   Replaced Printer   8/6/2015
Jack Hill   Jones    WC     52585258    WC/ description   Replaced Scangun   8/7/2015
Jack Hill   Johnson  WD     12457898    WD/ description   Replaced Scangun   8/8/2015
Jack Hill   Clinton  Core   45698523    Core/ description Replaced printer   8/8/2015
Jack Hill   Smith   WA      32589654    WA/ description   WOA                8/8/2015
```

The current code I have is this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Format(Log.Date_,"ddd") AS [Day], LOG.Date_,
                (select COUNT(*) FROM LOG
                 Where Zone_of_call = "WFF") AS WA
FROM LOG
WHERE (((LOG.Date_) >= [Start Date] And (LOG.Date_) <= [End Date]))
ORDER BY LOG.Date_;
```

Where the database is LOG. I skipped techs and dispatches and jumped to the Columns for the daily count of each case by zone.

Comment: Maybe this help https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Video-Pivot-your-data-in-Access-f3f72ecc-6550-4fbc-8775-5e48e88ade25?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE  . Btw dont post your data as picture, we cant copy / paste from pictures.

Comment: I am using Access 2013 which I believe does not support pivot tables. I cant export the data to excel because the database grows daily. Any other tips?

Comment: It does. Look for the guide for creating queries, then select the wizard for crosstab queries.